# Which controls triggered the Page.IsValid = false?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation

Two things:

1. Is it possible to set the Page.IsValid (Is_Valid) property through Jquery so that I dont have to use the aspx validators? It is my understanding that the IsValid property is read-only?
2. When the validators are in, is it possible to find out, through Jquery (ofcourse) which controls caused the validation to fail? An example would be a form with loads of text boxes: user clicks the button and I get my results in a validation summary. All fine and dandy. But I also want to let the users know which controls they are by changing the respective textbox background to lets say, red.

Now the hack for that would be that I call my own JS function that checks all the textboxes for validation (again) and then change the css to invalid ones to show red. But I would have thought there surely must be a way to identity which controls failed the validation?

Any insight?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(A)` is not possible. `Page.IsValid` is set by server-side validation and the client should not mess with it. Client-side validation doesn't post back if it fails anyway, so `Page.Validate()` isn't even called in that case.

The [AJAX Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/) achieves `(B)` by rebinding the validation functions. You can try something like the following:

*[Disclaimer: I'm not as familiar with jQuery (yet), so I'll use plain JS. Feel free to translate to the appropriate jQuery idioms.]*

```
for (var i = 0; i < window.Page_Validators.length; ++i) {
    var validator = window.Page_Validators[i];
    validator.__old_evaluationfunction = validator.evaluationfunction;
    validator.evaluationfunction = function(value) {
        var element = validator.controltovalidate;
        if (!validator.__old_evaluationfunction(value)) {
            // Validation failed - turn `element` red, scream at the user, etc.
            return false;
        } else {
            // Validation succeeded - restore `element` to its normal state.
            return true;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: for some reason the validation is not firing with regular expression validators. Any idea??

Comment: it debugged and it was something wrong at my end. Bravo for wonderful answer

Answer (score 2):

All validation controls do server validation for sure. Overriding isvalid=false from client side can only prevent postback to happen. At serverside and client side you can enumerate through collection of validators and each ctrl have IsValid property.